# Uso de espaço com std::cin

Tags: c++

Não estou conseguindo fazer com que o vetor imprima os caracteres após o uso do espaço.

Segue aqui apenas um trecho do meu programa aonde estou tendo dificuldades:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    char caracteres[20];
    
    cout <<"Digite um vetor de caracteres: ";
    
    cin >> caracteres;
    
    cout << "Os caracteres digitados foram: " << caracteres;
    return 0;
}
```

O  `cout` só tá imprimindo a primeira palava do vetor, por exemplo: **'ana'** ; Porém, se eu colocar **'anna souza'** , irá somente sair o **'anna'** , ignorando tudo o que vem após o espaço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema não é o espaço dentro do "vetor", a questão é como o `std::cin` funciona, ele começará a ler quando se trata do primeiro caractere que não seja espaço em branco (espaços, tabulações, quebras de linha) e parará de ler quando chegar ao próximo espaço em branco. Em outras palavras, ele só lê uma palavra de cada vez.

Por exemplo:

```
string foo, bar, baz;

cout << "Digite 3 palavras: ";

cin >> foo >> bar >> baz;

cout << endl << "foo: " << foo << endl;
cout << "bar: " << bar << endl;
cout << "baz: " << baz << endl;
```

Se digitar algo como: `Ola Mundo Novo` vai obter os valores nas 3 variáveis, exemplo online: https://ideone.com/5PnmF1, a saída será:

> foo: Ola
>
> bar: Mundo
>
> baz: Novo

Para resolver da forma que deseja basta usar a função `std::getline()` que é própria para obter "a linha" (ainda irá ignorar quebra de linha), exemplo:

```
string sentenca;

cout << "Digite 3 palavras: ";

getline(cin, sentenca);

cout << endl << "sentenca: " << sentenca << endl;
```

Exemplo online: https://ideone.com/uWYqLm

A saída será:

> sentenca: Ola Mundo Novo

No caso de um *char array* com tamanho, deve usar

```
std::istream::getline(char* s, streamsize n)
```

No caso `std::cin.getline()` para especificar o tamanho, ficando assim:

```
char sentenca[20];

cout << "Digite 3 palavras: ";

cin.getline(sentenca, 20);

cout << endl << "sentenca: " << sentenca << endl;
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!